# How do I pull the string array from this json object?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get a list of available numbers from the following json object, using the class from `org.json`

```
    {
        "response":true,
        "state":1,
        "data":
        {
            "CALLERID":"81101099",
            "numbers":
                [
                       "21344111","21772917",
                       "28511113","29274472",
                       "29843999","29845591",
                       "30870001","30870089",
                       "30870090","30870091"
                ]
        }
    }
```

My first steps were, after receiving the json object from the web service:

```
jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
jsonData = jsonObj.optJSONObject("data");
```

Now, how do I save the string array of numbers?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

use:

```
jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
jsonData = jsonObj.optJSONObject("data");
JSONArray arrJson = jsonData.getJSONArray("numbers");
String[] arr = new String[arrJson.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < arrJson.length(); i++)
    arr[i] = arrJson.getString(i);
```

Comment: Except for the fact that there's no method in JSONArray named getLength(did you mean length() ? ) this was great - thanks :)

Comment: If you're specifying strings, it looks like you have to cast the value of arrJson.get(i) to String.

Comment: It shows null pointer exception. `getString(i)` retrieves the value in the form of string. But in OP's case the JSONArray's elements do not have value.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `JSONArray` to pull data in an array

```
JSONObject jObj= new JSONObject(your_json_response);
JSONArray array = jObj.getJSONArray("data");
```

Answer (score 1):

My code is for getting "data":

```
public void jsonParserArray(String json) {

        String [] resultsNumbers = new String[100];

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObjectGetData = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONObject jsonObjectGetNumbers = jsonObjectGetData.optJSONObject("results");
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObjectGetNumbers.getJSONArray("numbers");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                resultsNumbers[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to get it in a javascript block, Try something like this

var arrNumber = jsonData.numbers;