# JSON extract values from key

Tags: java, json

I have a String. I am converting it to JSONOBJECT and I am trying to extract the values based on the key.

JSON STRING:

```
jsonString="
{
\"AREA\": [\"IT,SALES\"],
\"CITY\": [\"LA\",\"NORTH\"]
}";
```

I want the values of "AREA"in one string and CITY in one String. I have tried :

```
JSONObject jsonOb = new JSONObject("jsonString");
String area = jsonOb.getString("AREA");
```

But I am not able to retrieve the values in that way. Need some suggestions.

Comment: What do you call "jsonString" ?

Comment: @SegFault Updated my question. Sorry. jsonString the json itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pull the string array from this json object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373398/how-do-i-pull-the-string-array-from-this-json-object)

Comment: So you should remove the `"` around `jsonString` since it is a variable: `new JSONObject(jsonString);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were trying to access `Area` directly whereas it is a `JSONArray` Object.

```
String json="{\"AREA\": [\"IT,SALES\"],\"CITY\": [\"LA\", \"NORTH\"]}";
JSONObject jsonOb = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray arrJson=jsonOb.getJSONArray("AREA");

for(int i=0;i<arrJson.length();i++)
System.out.println(arrJson.getString(i));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONArray area = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("AREA");
Iterator<String> iterator = area.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

You should get a JSONArray object and then you can simply iterate and build the appropriate strings (using StringBuilder).

You can refer to [this article](https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) for further help.

Comment: Hi @Alon Segal. Thanks for the reply. I ma getting a typecast exception over here: "area.iterator();"

Answer (score 2):

Your data has `[]`, so use `getJSONArray("AREA")` and you can iterate over that.

(The method exactly would depend what library you have)

Comment: I am using org.json library here. @cricket_007

Comment: Okay, I think that method exists then. Basically, `getString("AREA")` will try to return a String, not the list that is in your data

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are after:

```
    String jsonString = "{\"AREA\": [\"IT,SALES\"],\"CITY\": [\"LA\",\"NORTH\"]}";
    JSONObject jObj;
    String areaString = "";
    String cityString = "";
    try
    {
        jObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        areaString = jObj.getJSONArray("AREA").toString();
        cityString = jObj.getJSONArray("CITY").toString();
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("areaString: " + areaString);
    System.out.println("cityString: " + cityString);
```